# Consulting of fortune tellers, palmists and astrologers

Tags: biblical-basis, divination

Are there verses in the Bible, especially the New Testament, forbidding believers from consulting fortune tellers, palmist and astrologers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search (and can be easily answered by a Google search)

Answer (score 1):

Deuteronomy 18:10: “There shall not be found among you . . . anyone who practices divination or tells fortunes or interprets omens.”

Compared to God’s truth, divination is false, deceitful, and worthless. See Acts 16, as well.

Divination is a sin. Any form of it. Stay clear. Wisdom only comes from God.